# Exercise: establishing if some sets are vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $f:V\longrightarrow W$ be a linear map and $U, T$ be subspaces of $V$ and $W$ respectively.

1. Establish if the set $E=\{f\in\operatorname{Hom}(V, W):U\subseteq\operatorname{Ker}(f)\}$ is a vector space.
2. Establish if the set $F=\{f\in\operatorname{Hom}(V, W):\operatorname{Ker}(f)\subseteq U\}$ is a vector space.
3. Establish if the set $G=\{f\in\operatorname{Hom}(V, W):T\subseteq\operatorname{Im}(f)\}$ is a vector space.
4. Establish if the set $H=\{f\in\operatorname{Hom}(V, W):\operatorname{Im}(f)\subseteq T\}$ is a vector space.

**My attempt.** For the case 1., I have to verify that for every $\lambda_1, \lambda_2\in\mathbb K$, $f_1, f_2\in E$, the element $\lambda_1 f_1+\lambda_2f_2\in E$. This is true because obviously $U\subseteq\operatorname{Ker}(\lambda_1f_1+\lambda_2f_2)$. The same for case 3. Due to the same argument, for the cases 2. and 4., the sets $F$ and $H$ are not vector spaces. Is this attempt correct?

Thank You

Comment: Nothing. You have to verify simply when those sets are vector spaces.

Answer (score 1):

For $E$ and $F$ it's correct (unless $U=V$ when $F=\{0\}$, otherwise $F$ doesn't contain the $0$ map).

For the other two it's the other way around: $H$ is a vector spaces but $G$ is not (unless $T=\{0\}$). Can you see why?

Comment: $G$ is not a vector space since it does not contain the zero element unless $T=\{0\}$. Why $E$? The zero element is contained in $E$ since obviously $U\subseteq V$.

Comment: No, the same goes for $E$: the zero element has full kernel so only the trivial case $U=V$ can work.

Comment: And what about $F$? To be a vector space it must contain the zero element, that is the condition $V\subseteq U$ must hold. So is $F$ a vector space?

Comment: Yes, I got confused, sorry. I update my answer.